# Is this statement valid for positive $x$ and $y$? If $x>y$, then $\frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{y}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

Is this following statement valid (where both $x$ and $y$ are positive)?

> If $x>y$, then $\dfrac{1}{x} < \dfrac{1}{y}$.

Comment: You have written two relations. What are you wanting to validate? That either one implies the other?

Comment: @Blue if the first expression is true, is second true?

Comment: Hint: Division by a positive number preserves the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample (posted before OP added the condition that $x$ and $y$ are positive):

Let $x=1$ and $y=-1$, the first inequality is $1 > -1$ but the second would become $1 < -1$.

To see that the result holds:

multiply both sides by $\frac1{xy}$.

Comment: What about if both x and y are positive?

Comment: multiply the first inequality by $\frac1{xy}$ to see it.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh The problem specifies that both $x$ and $y$ are positive.

Comment: @JohnDouma: OP added the positivity condition in reaction to this answer.

Comment: @Blue Thanks for the clarification. I missed that.

Comment: Thank you @Blue =)

Answer (score 0):

Because $$\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x-y}{xy}>0.$$

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what axioms you were taught.

But the three basics are

0) for any $x,y $ exactly one of the following is true: $x <y $ or $y <x$ or $x=y $.

1) if $x<y $ then for all $c$ we have $x+c <y+c $  and

2) if $x <y $ and $a>0$ the $ax <ay $.

So in a proof by contradiction:

If $\frac 1x \le \frac 1y $ then

$\frac 1xx \le \frac 1y x$

$1\le \frac xy $

$1*y\le \frac xyy $

$y\le x $

Which is a contradiction so $\frac 1x >\frac 1y $